# Why won't CountDownTimer start onTick when it should?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I've searched everywhere for an answer to this dilemma. A CountDownTimer(bsCountDownTimer) will not start when it should. When I click the button, it is supposed to begin the onTick(), correct? However, only after I navigate to a different activity and navigate backwards using the UP button, or exit the app or destroy it and restart it does the onTick() start updating the text and sending information to LogCat like it is told to do.

My best guess is that this problem is exclusive to either the CDT sub-class, onBsButtonClick(), onCreate(), or possible onResume()/onPause().

Here is some of the source code.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        if(bsTimeStamp!=0){bsIsRunning=true;}
        if(bsTimeStamp==0){bsIsRunning=false;}


        lastFed=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastFedTextView);
        feedAt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedAtTextView);
        daysText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDays);
        hoursText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHours);
        minutesText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMinutes);
        daysText.setText("");
        hoursText.setText("");
        minutesText.setText("");


        // get timeStamp and boolean from onFeedButtonClick() START
        final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        feedClickTimeStamp = prefs.getLong("savedOnFeedClick", placeholder);
        bsTimeStamp = prefs.getLong("savedOnBsClick", bsProgress);
        bsPlaceholder = prefs.getLong("saved placeholder", bsPlaceholder);
        bsIsRunning = prefs.getBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning);
        progressbs = Long.toString(bsProgress);
        placeholderbs = Long.toString(bsPlaceholder);
        timestampbs = Long.toString(bsTimeStamp);

        timestamp = Long.toString(feedClickTimeStamp);
        LAST_FED = prefs.getString("lastFed", LAST_FED);
        FEED_AT = prefs.getString("feedAt", FEED_AT);
        feedAt.setText("Feed at: " + FEED_AT);
        lastFed.setText("Last fed at: " + LAST_FED);
        // get timeStamp and boolean from onFeedButtonClick() END


        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        long currentTime = date.getMillis();



        Long bsDiffInMillis;
            if(bsIsRunning=false) {
                bsDiffInMillis = 0L;
            }
            else {
                bsDiffInMillis = currentTime - bsTimeStamp;
                bsPlaceholder -= bsDiffInMillis;
            }


            Integer bsDiffInt = Integer.valueOf(bsDiffInMillis.intValue());
            int roundedDiff = (bsDiffInt + 500) / 1000 * 1000;


        j += roundedDiff - 2000;


// BS PROGRESS BAR START

        bsProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.bsProgressBar);
        bsProgressBar.setProgress(j);

        Long bsPlaceholderLong = bsPlaceholder;
        final Integer setMax = Integer.valueOf(bsPlaceholderLong.intValue());

        bsProgressBar.setMax(setMax);
        setProgressBarVisibility(true);   

        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            bsProgressBar.setRotation(180);
        } else{
            // FIND A WAY TO ROTATE PROGRESSBAR BEFORE API 11 (3.0)
        }

        timeDisplayBs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown)).setText(convertMillisForCrafting(bsPlaceholder-ji));

        millisInFuture = bsPlaceholder;

        bsCountDownTimer = new CDT(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);


//  START BS BUTTON LISTENER //         
            final Button startBsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsButton);  
            startBsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onBsButtonClick(view);
                } //close onClick

            }); //close onClickListener
//  END BS BUTTON LISTENER //       

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {} else {}
    }// onCreate END 


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bsCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bsIsRunning = prefs.getBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning);


        if(feedClickTimeStamp>0){
            mountCountDownTimer.start();
        }
        if(bsIsRunning==true) {

            bsCountDownTimer.start();
            bsIsRunning=true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning).commit();
        }
        if(bsIsRunning==false){
            bsIsRunning=false;
            String progressBarTitleBs = "blacksmithing research";
            timeDisplayBs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);
            timeDisplayBs.setText(progressBarTitleBs.toUpperCase(preferredLocale));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning).commit();
        }
    }

    public class CDT extends CountDownTimer {

        public CDT(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            millisInFuture = prefs.getLong("saved placeholder", bsPlaceholder);
            timeDisplayBs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisInFuture) {
            Log.v("bsTimer", "Tick of Progress " + ji + " " + millisInFuture);
            ji+=1;
            j+=1000;
            bsProgressBar.setProgress(j);

            timeDisplayBs.setText(convertMillisForCrafting(millisInFuture-ji));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            bsCountDownTimer.cancel();
            j=0;
            ji=0;
            bsPlaceholder = 0;
            bsTimeStamp = 0;
            bsProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            String progressBarTitleBs = "blacksmithing research";
            timeDisplayBs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);
            timeDisplayBs.setText(progressBarTitleBs.toUpperCase(preferredLocale));
        }

    }


        public void onBsButtonClick(View view) {

            final SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bsTimeStamp = prefs.getLong("savedOnBsClick", bsProgress);
            bsPlaceholder = prefs.getLong("saved placeholder", bsPlaceholder);
            bsIsRunning = prefs.getBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning);

            EditText daysText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDays);
            EditText hoursText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHours);
            EditText minutesText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMinutes);
            int daysPh;
            int hoursPh;
            int minutesPh;
            String daysStr = daysText.getText().toString();
            String hoursStr = hoursText.getText().toString();
            String minutesStr = minutesText.getText().toString();




            if (daysStr.matches("") && hoursStr.matches("") && minutesStr.matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter DAYS, HOURS, or MINUTES.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if(bsIsRunning==false){

                bsPlaceholder = 0;
                bsTimeStamp = 0;
                bsIsRunning=true;
                j=0;
                bsProgressBar.setProgress(0);

                Long bsPlaceholderLong = bsPlaceholder;
                final Integer setMax = Integer.valueOf(bsPlaceholderLong.intValue());

                bsProgressBar.setMax(setMax);

                if(daysText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    daysText.setText("0");
                }
                if(hoursText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    hoursText.setText("0");
                }
                if(minutesText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    minutesText.setText("0");
                }


                daysPh = Integer.parseInt(daysText.getText().toString());
                hoursPh = Integer.parseInt(hoursText.getText().toString());
                minutesPh = Integer.parseInt(minutesText.getText().toString());
                daysText.setText("");
                hoursText.setText("");
                minutesText.setText("");

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                bsPlaceholder = getMillisForCrafting(daysPh, hoursPh, minutesPh);
                millisInFuture = bsPlaceholder;                         //VITAL
                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                bsProgress = dt.getMillis();

                editor.putBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning).commit();
                editor.putLong("savedOnBsClick", bsProgress).commit();
                editor.putLong("saved placeholder", bsPlaceholder).commit();



                bsCountDownTimer.start();
            } //close if bsIsRunning==false

            else if(bsIsRunning==true){
                view.invalidate();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                .setTitle("New Blacksmithing Research Timer? (erases current)")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to start a new timer? \n(Current timer will be erased.)")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            bsPlaceholder = 0;
                            bsTimeStamp = 0;
                            bsCountDownTimer.cancel();
                            bsIsRunning=true;
                            j=0;
                            bsProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            String progressBarTitleBs = "blacksmithing research";
                            timeDisplayBs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);
                            timeDisplayBs.setText(progressBarTitleBs.toUpperCase(preferredLocale));

                            EditText daysText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDays);
                            EditText hoursText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHours);
                            EditText minutesText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMinutes);



                            if(daysText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                daysText.setText("0");
                            }
                            if(hoursText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                hoursText.setText("0");
                            }
                            if(minutesText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                minutesText.setText("0");
                            }

                            int daysPh = Integer.parseInt(daysText.getText().toString());
                            int hoursPh = Integer.parseInt(hoursText.getText().toString());
                            int minutesPh = Integer.parseInt(minutesText.getText().toString());

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            bsPlaceholder = getMillisForCrafting(daysPh, hoursPh, minutesPh);
                            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                            bsProgress = dt.getMillis();

                            editor.putBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning).commit();
                            editor.putLong("savedOnBsClick", bsProgress).commit();
                            editor.putLong("saved placeholder", bsPlaceholder).commit();

                            Long bsPlaceholderLong = bsPlaceholder;
                            final Integer setMax = Integer.valueOf(bsPlaceholderLong.intValue());

                            bsProgressBar.setMax(setMax);

                            daysText.setText("");
                            hoursText.setText("");
                            minutesText.setText("");

                            bsCountDownTimer.start();



                        }
                 })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                 })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
            }return;

        }

            public static Long getMillisForCrafting(int daysPh, int hoursPh, int minutesPh) {
                    Locale.getDefault();
                    DateTime bs = new DateTime();
                    daysPulled = daysPh;
                    hoursPulled = hoursPh;
                    minutesPulled = minutesPh;

                    final long nowInMillis = bs.getMillis();


                    long days = daysPulled * 86400000;
                    long hours = hoursPulled * 3600000;
                    long minutes = minutesPulled * 60000;
                    long millisToAddToNow = days + hours + minutes;
                    long futureDateInMillis = millisToAddToNow + nowInMillis;
                    long millisFromDate = futureDateInMillis - nowInMillis;




                    return millisFromDate;
                }


            public void onBsResetButtonClick(View view) {
                final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bsTimeStamp = prefs.getLong("savedOnBsClick", bsProgress);
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Reset Timer?")
                            .setMessage("Reset Blacksmithing Research timer? \n(Current timer will be erased.)")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                                    j=0;
                                    bsProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                    bsCountDownTimer.cancel();
                                    bsIsRunning=false;

                                    String progressBarTitleBs = "blacksmithing research";
                                    timeDisplayBs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown);
                                    timeDisplayBs.setText(progressBarTitleBs.toUpperCase(preferredLocale));

                                    bsPlaceholder = 0;
                                    bsTimeStamp = 0;
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                                    editor.putBoolean("bs is running", bsIsRunning).commit();
                                    editor.putLong("savedOnBsClick", 0).commit();
                                    editor.putLong("saved placeholder", 0).commit();

                                    // CLEAR INPUT EDITTEXT AREAS
                                    EditText daysText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDays);
                                    EditText hoursText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHours);
                                    EditText minutesText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMinutes);
                                    daysText.setText("");
                                    hoursText.setText("");
                                    minutesText.setText("");
                                    // CLEAR INPUT EDITTEXT AREAS

                                }})
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                             })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();

                        }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") 
    public static String convertMillis(long milliseconds){
        long seconds, minutes, hours;
        seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;

        Locale.getDefault();
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        return(time);
        }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") 
    public static String convertMillisForCrafting(long milliseconds){
        long seconds, minutes, hours, days;
        seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        hours = minutes / 60;
        days = hours / 24;
        hours = hours % 24;

        minutes = minutes % 60;

        Locale.getDefault();
        String timeBs = String.format("%02d days %02d hours %02d minutes %02d seconds", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
        return(timeBs);
        }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass

        mProgressBar.destroyDrawingCache();
        mountCountDownTimer.cancel();
//      bsProgressBar.destroyDrawingCache();
//      bsCountDownTimer.cancel();
//      android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing(); // Stop method tracing that the activity started during onCreate()
    }

}
```

Comment: After reviewing your code, I believe that your problem maybe more of a simple logical issue. I haven't solved it but I will say that I think you need to check your variable bsIsRunning (Boolean) is correctly set. Having it incorrectly set would cause the issue of be called onResume() which would make sense why it starts when you switch activities and and navigate it starts but when you want it other wise it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am going to investigate bsIsRunning in all instances. However, in order to improve this question for any others that may be reading it, the problem described in the question predates the creation of the bsIsRunning boolean variable. In other words, I had this problem before I made that variable and placed it in multiple places.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it!

The countDownTimer wouldn't start because the variable from onBsButtonClick() (bsPlaceholder) wasn't being passed into onCreate() correctly.

Here's what I did:

Declared a global variable

```
static long timeInput;
```

Created a sub-class that extends CountDownTimer:

```
    public class bsTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public bsTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisInFuture) {
        Log.v("bsTimer", "Tick of Progress " + ji + " " + millisInFuture);
        ji+=1;
        j+=1000;
        bsProgressBar.setProgress(j);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.bs_countdown)).setText(convertMillisForCrafting(millisInFuture-ji));

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Instantiated the countdown timer in onCreate();

```
bsCountDownTimer = new bsTimer(timeInput, 1000);
```

Then just made a new timer and started it in the onBsButtonClick() method!

```
bsCountDownTimer = new bsTimer(timeInput, 1000).start();
```